# What are the original 16 base cards in Smash Up?

Tags: smash-up

A friend loaned me Smash Up with all the expansions but I'd like to start out playing just the "base" set.  Which 16 bases should I use?

(He already removed the duplicate bases from Level 9000 so I cannot identify them that way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every base is keyed to a faction. It's pretty easy to determine with which faction a base is associated, so look for the bases associated with the factions from the original game. If there are ambiguities, keep in mind that each faction has two kindred bases.

Bases from the original game:

- Jungle Oasis
- Tar Pits
- The Grey Opal
- Tortuga
- Mushroom Kingdom
- Cave of Shinies
- Evans City Cemetery
- Rhodes Plaza Mall
- The Central Brain
- Factory 436-1337
- The Mothership
- The Homeworld
- Temple of Goju
- Ninja Dojo
- The Great Library
- School of Wizardry

Comment: Thanks, looking at it again the colors helped clarify some of the ones I was unsure of because they correspond with the colors of the factions.